# after bundle, vuetify takes 500kb bundle size

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am building for production. `npm run build --report` .

I am using vue and vuetify.

Looks like after running the above command,  I can see that vuetify takes lots of space after bundling.

```
stat size: 1.05MB
parsed size: 500kb
gziped size: 102kb.
```

Looks like 500kb is really huge. Why is this happening? how can I lower it ?

I tried using a-la-carte and from 500kb, it got reduced to 360kb. I am not using lots of components, though.

Comment: This wouldn't surprise me. Vuetify is a decently big library

Comment: are there any less huge libraries for vue.js instead of vuetify?

Comment: There are alot of good ui frameworks out there for vue. I would shop around. [Buefy](https://buefy.org/) is pretty lightweight. Another option is to load just the css of these frameworks and build out the js functionality yourself. It all comes down to what you need and what trade offs you are willing to take.

Comment: The other confusing part is the installer added a path `import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'`, but the online docs claim it's "automatic" and to use `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'`.  I couldn't make that happy with TypeScript which I'm also second guessing was a mistake to even attempt.  Spend more time configuring and less time coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the official `vuetify loader` and let it *tree shake* and `a-la-carte` for you.  And use webpack or vue-cli-3 to *bundle the vuetify code into a separate download*.

It might be a bit `large`, but your users won't regret the extra download size, especially if it needs to happen only the first time in a separate bundle.

Comment: Do you have any up-to-date links to that? I'd like to learn more about this "tree-shake" method in vuetify.

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader